# CRichEditCtrl prevent auto scroll on SetSel

Tags: c++, mfc, cricheditctrl

I have a CMyRichEditCtrl class inheriting from CRichEditCtrl. When I call SetSel, it automatically scrolls the contents of the CRichEditCtrl so that the caret is visible. I would like to avoid this behavior.

What is bugging me it that this behavior seems to have changed between 6.0 and other versions.

**Visual Studio 2010** : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4zek9k1f(v=vs.100).aspx

> The caret is placed at the end of the selection indicated by the greater of the start (cpMin or nStartChar) and end (cpMax or nEndChar) indices. **This function *scrolls* the contents of the CRichEditCtrl so that the caret is visible.**

**Visual Studio 6.0**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa313352(v=vs.60).aspx

> The caret is placed at the end of the selection indicated by the greater of the start (cpMin or nStartChar) and end (cpMax or nEndChar) indices. **This function *does not scroll* the contents of the CRichEditCtrl so that the caret is visible.**

Is there a way to prevent the auto-scroll of the control when calling SetSel ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was not an easy one, but I finally found a workaround.

```
void CMyRichEditCtrl::doStuff()
{
    SetRedraw( FALSE );

    int nOldFirstVisibleLine = GetFirstVisibleLine();

    // Save current selection
    long lMinSel, lMaxSel;
    GetSel( lMinSel, lMaxSel );

    // Do something here
    doSomething();

    // Restore selection
    SetSel( lMinSel, lMaxSel );

    // Prevent the auto-scroll of the control when calling SetSel()
    int nNewFirstVisibleLine = GetFirstVisibleLine();

    if( nOldFirstVisibleLine != nNewFirstVisibleLine )
        LineScroll( nOldFirstVisibleLine - nNewFirstVisibleLine );

    SetRedraw( TRUE );

    RedrawWindow();
 }
```

Comment: I would like to add here that hiding and showing selection using HideSelection() in the above block will drastically improve the performance. I just discovered it.

Answer (score 0):

Use CRichEditCtrl::SetOptions method or the below code to disable and enable auto-scroll. hwnd is the handled to the rich edit control.

You can use the following code to disable auto-scroll:

```
LRESULT prevOptions = SendMessage(hwnd, EM_GETOPTIONS, 0, 0);
SendMessage(hwnd, EM_SETOPTIONS, ECOOP_SET, prevOptions & ~ECO_AUTOVSCROLL);
```

And enable it back using:

```
SendMessage(hwnd, EM_SETOPTIONS, ECOOP_SET, prevOptions);
```

Answer (score -2):

Change to

RedrawWindow(0,0,RDW_NOERASE);

It's better.

Comment: You should add this as a comment to the previos answer from @MasterMind, not as a new answer as this doesn't answer the question of the OP.

Comment: @user3073563: When I replace RedrawWindow() by RedrawWindow(0,0,RDW_NOERASE), the RichEditCtrl doesn't display characters anymore and behaves erratically... did you even try this before saying it's better?